# running a cron job on a time interval

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

Is it possible to run a job for 2 hours at a specific time? So lets say I want to run wget command that calls/hits an endpoint in my web app for 2 consecutive hours in a day. Meaning that every single minute I want to hit this end point for the allocated 2 hour time slot. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you want to run the command every minute between the hours of 1am and 3am:

```
* 1-2 * * *  /path/to/command
```

Add that to your crontab with `crontab -e`

EDIT: originally had this as 1-3, which as @ruifeng pointed out, means run your command at every minute from 1:00am to 3:59am.

Comment: what if it is 1pm-3pm ? @xofer

Comment: @user79356 is `man cron` broken on your system?

Answer (score 2):

```
* 1-3 * * *  /path/to/command
```

means run your command at every minute from 1:00am to 3:59am

to run the command every minute between the hours of 1am and 3am
you need run

```
* 1-2 * * *  /path/to/command
```

Comment: Good point, +1, updated my answer